# New tasks don't wait for GCD Barriers

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I learned a bit about GCD barriers and wanted to examine this information (from [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1452797-dispatch_barrier_async)):

> Any blocks submitted after the barrier block are not executed until the barrier block completes.

By this code:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < 500, i++) {
  dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSLog("%d", i);
  }
  if ((i % 50) == 0) {
    dispatch_barrier_async(queue, ^{
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
        NSLog(@"Barrier!");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I was expecting that each 50th count, the queue will be stopped for 5 seconds, but this is not the case. Instead, barriers executes in parallel with other tasks, and all tasks despite barriers executes immediatelly. Is the docs wrong or i misunderstand somethin? Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you create your queue using: `queue = dispatch_queue_create("SomeName", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you misread the next paragraph in the docs

> The queue you specify should be a concurrent queue that you create
>   yourself using the dispatch_queue_create function. If the queue you
>   pass to this function is a serial queue or one of the global
>   concurrent queues, this function behaves like the dispatch_async
>   function.

ie

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
```

will not act as a barrier but instead a normal dispatch_async